# Is my monitor faulty and I need to return it, or is there a quick fix?

Tags: display, external-display

I just bought a BenQ RL2455HM monitor. I was really excited until I opened the box, connected the power lead and turned on the monitor to see that it is not working properly.

I cannot post any photos to show you the exact problem, because I don't have enough reputation, but this is basically what happens: the top half of the screen works fine, the bottom half of the screen shows the background color and some vertical lines (as if the monitor is showing the same horizontal line of pixels all throughout the bottom half of the screen). This happens even when you turn on the monitor on the BenQ purple start-up screen. This means that the problem is not in my HDMI cable.

Also, sometimes when I power the monitor on, black horizontal lines appear on the faulty part of the screen, then if I turn it off and turn it back on they either disappear or they don't, but they changed place and change in number.

My question is: do you think the monitor is faulty beyond repair and I need to return it or there is a simple way to fix this? Also, what is the most possible reason for such a malfunction on a LED monitor?

Here’s what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: You say you just bought it; does the monitor come with any warranty then?

Comment: Paragraphs, please. You can also include links to images, people with more rep can then inline them.

Comment: Given that you use HDMI as a connection, which is digital it is possible the problem could be in the cable, but as you describe that it also happens in the menu, its most likely a fault in the monitor. I'd get in contact with the store where you bought it and see if they can replace it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added some paragraphs an a link to a photo with the start-up screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to assume that the screen is broken, especially if it is exactly half of it as it would suggest a wiring issue. Return and replace it.

Comment: This is probably what I'm going to do, but since I bought it from an internet retailer I wanted to avoid the hustle of returning it and probably learning more about monitors being a PC enthusiast. It's new, though, so I wouldn't want to risk ruining it if it's a complicated fix.

Comment: Yeah. It's most likely an issue with the wiring or processor. Not something that can easily be fixed.

Comment: Oh, dear... Thanks a lot, I will contact the seller tomorrow, I'll hopefully get a working unit assuming it's a factory defect, not one arising from mishandling the unit on behalf of the postal services.

Comment: Have other monitors worked in the past?

Comment: This is the first monitor I'm trying, but the problem persists even I unplug the HMDI cable and try turning the monitor on.

Comment: It's definitely the monitor then